# reviewboard:A repository was not found at the specified path

Tags: repository, cvs, review-board

I am using ReviewBoard 1.7.7 installed on Linux Redhat 6 .

I get the `A repository was not found at the specified path` error message when I try to create a `CVS` RevfiewBoard Repository, using

```
:pserver:review_board@localhost:/home/cvsroot
```

and entering my username and password.  I also tried other
combinations, like

`localhost:/home/cvsroot` and

```
:pserver:review_board:review_board_pw@localhost:/home/cvsroot
```

and entering my username and password.

Otherwise, I am able to use cvs on the machine where I have ReviewBoard installed with the username review_board, to do checkouts, diffs, etc.

Comment: Try adding port :2401 in your connection string... see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the repository path as: 
:pserver:review_board@:/home/cvsroot

= name of the host which runs ReviewBoard.